# Unable to link sliderInput with selectInput to manipulate the donut chart

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have been trying to link my slider (which has years) with selectInput dropdown (which has freedom factors). I have been getting the donut chart, but it is equally distributed. I wish to choose options in dropdown and change their trends with the slider. I know something is wrong in output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({}), but not sure what is it.

global.r

```
df3<-  df1[, (names(df1) %in% c("year","region","pf_rol",   "pf_ss_homicide","pf_ss_disappearances_fatalities", "pf_ss_women_fgm", "pf_ss_women_inheritance", "pf_religion","pf_association_sport","pf_association_political",  "pf_expression_internet", "pf_identity_sex", "ef_legal_judicial", "ef_legal_military",  "ef_money_growth",  "ef_trade_tariffs_revenue", "ef_regulation_business_start","ef_regulation_business_bribes"
))]


netgraph <- df3 %>%
  group_by(year,region)%>%
  summarise_all(mean)

longdata <- gather(netgraph, key="freedom_factors", value="value", c("pf_rol",  "pf_ss_homicide","pf_ss_disappearances_fatalities", "pf_ss_women_fgm", "pf_ss_women_inheritance", "pf_religion","pf_association_sport","pf_association_political",  "pf_expression_internet", "pf_identity_sex", "ef_legal_judicial", "ef_legal_military",  "ef_money_growth",  "ef_trade_tariffs_revenue", "ef_regulation_business_start","ef_regulation_business_bribes"))

select_ops <- unique(longdata$freedom_factors)
```

server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  years <- reactive({
   longdata %>%
     filter(year == input$yearslong)})

 selectfreedom <- reactive({
   longdata %>%
     filter(freedom_factors == input$variable)})

output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    donut <- selectfreedom() %>%
      group_by(region) %>%
      summarise(mean(value)) %>%
      plot_ly(labels = ~region, values = ~value) %>%
      add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
      layout(title = "Donut charts using Plotly",  showlegend = F,
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
    dput(longdata)
    })

})
```

ui.r

```
dashboardPage( 
    dashboardHeader(title = "Human Freedom Index", titleWidth = 300),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sliderInput("years","Select Year:",
                  min = min(df1$year),
                  max = max(df1$year),
                  value = min(df1$year),
                  step = 1),
selectInput("variable","Select Freedom Factor:",
                  c("Rule of Law"= "pf_rol",
                                  "Homicides Reported" = "pf_ss_homicide",
                                  "Women Dissapearances"="pf_ss_disappearances_violent",
                                  "Deaths by Terrorism"="pf_ss_disappearances_fatalities",
                                  "Female Mutiliation"= "pf_ss_women_fgm",
                                  "Women Inheritance" = "pf_ss_women_inheritance",
                                  "Freedom of Religion" = "pf_religion")),

 dashboardBody(
          fluidRow(
        box(plotlyOutput("plot2"), width=15, height=400)
      )
    )
  )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this correction -

```
selectfreedom <- reactive({
   years() %>%
     filter(freedom_factors == input$variable)})
```